# C# Read Password from Console without showing it

Tags: c#, console

If i use Console.ReadLine() to read a password then all the text entered is visible on the console. How can i read the password without making it visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Console.ReadKey(true)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw(v=vs.110).aspx),and concatenate internally chars into a string